# String manipulation in foreach powershell

Tags: arrays, string, powershell, loops

The output of this code is confusing me. I'm almost positive it's my logic on this.

I want to loop through the $stringToEdit Variable and replace the 'replace' text with an element of the $ip collection.

The output does give three blocks as expected but the 'replace' has ALL three of the elements. I thought it should only be each element. What am I doing wrong?

Code is below

```
$ip = @('172.168.1.1','172.168.3.1','172.168.2.1')
$stringToEdit = @"
    {
        address : replace
        interface : 'nic0'
        policy : 'allow'
        prefix : 32
    },
"@
$array = @()
$array = ForEach($entry in $ip) {
    $stringToEdit -replace "replace","$ip"
}
$array
```

Output is

```
{
    address : 172.168.1.1 172.168.3.1 172.168.2.1
    interface : 'nic0'
    policy : 'allow'
    prefix : 32
},
{
    address : 172.168.1.1 172.168.3.1 172.168.2.1
    interface : 'nic0'
    policy : 'allow'
    prefix : 32
},
{
    address : 172.168.1.1 172.168.3.1 172.168.2.1
    interface : 'nic0'
    policy : 'allow'
    prefix : 32
},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use the wrong variable in your foreach block
Replace this line:

```
$stringToEdit -replace "replace","$ip"
```

With this:

```
$stringToEdit -replace "replace","$entry"
```

Answer (score 0):

replace $ip with $entry

```
$stringToEdit -replace "replace","$entry"
```

Comment: Can you expand a bit on why your solution solves the problem?

Comment: I wanted this to use this to as a piece of code for a tool to add new entries in to a firewall. The code takes the string and the only thing that changed is the part i put replace in. I then to looped through each ip in the list and replaced the 'replace' text with the ip and then I added it to the array so in the end the output is showing what I want and I can just use this code in correlation with other code to add new entries on the fly or with a csv.